# How do i send response from Raspberry Pi to a web client

Tags: python, node.js, raspberry-pi3

I am doing a project on Attendance Tracking using Raspberry Pi. I have used Python with opencv for this. I have installed python and opencv in RPi. Next I trained the system with already available faces of some students. Then I trained those faces and stored the training data in a separate file. Then using Picamera I captured the image and did the recognition part with already available trained data. When I did everything separately everything works fine.

But I have some confusing questions in my mind!

1) How can I run the code in raspberry pi via Android app?

2) How do I send the correctly identified face labels to the android app?

I need to do it with node.js. If it's possible please guide me.

Comment: Your RPi has to run a web server (or at least listen for connections on a socket), you can do it in Node.js or in python (using Flask for example). The easiest way would be to trigger your function when a web page is called. In Node.js you can use a system call to start your python script. I really suggest you to take a look at Flask. It is very easy and it uses python so you stay in the same 'environment'. Good luck !

Comment: Suppose I use flask, is it possible to send data from RPi to a webclient calling it

Comment: Yep sure ! Depending on the complexity of your data, you can either just output plain text, or comma separated values or even JSON (using jsonify for example). In your android app, you'll have to parse your data but nothing really complicated here.

Comment: Ok i Installed flask in my RPi. I dont have a Desktop in my RPi. So i tried to run flask in my laptop on the same network as of RPi. but it showing unable to connect. Please help

Comment: You have to start flask on the RPi. You need to set the host to 0.0.0.0 so other devices on the network can access your webserver using your RPi's IP address : `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')` or `flask run --host=0.0.0.0` depending on how you start flask

Comment: ya! I tried these but doesn't work. Can you say how its achieved in nodejs

Comment: I won't be your guy for Node.js sorry :/

Comment: Yay! I installed Flask and its running fine! But now i need to run a python script which is in the same directory as app.py(config of flask) is. How do i get it right?